# DataAnnotation Localization Error when not translate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I work on an ASP.NET Core MVC website, Localization work well in Controller and View but I've an error with the localization of DataAnnotation :

My default language if English and I've ressources filename like : "Index.fr.resx" .
If the traduction in french is require, the traduction is use else the string key is return (the key is in English), 
but for DataAnnotation, traduction work well but when English is require, the website display an error :

`Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Intranet.Resources.ViewModels.News.Add.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly`

But the file is found because the traduction work, and for localization of Controller or View if English is required, the key string is returned and work well, any ideas ?

**Add.fr.resx :**

```
Title => Titre
```

**Add.cs**

```
[Display(Name = nameof(Resources.ViewModels.News.Add.Title), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ViewModels.News.Add))]
        public String Title { get; set; }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvc(
                config =>
                {
                    config.Filters.Add<ActionFilter>();
                })
                .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not seems to be possible to make a localization of display attribute in model so I just did it in the view :

```
placeholder="@Localizer[Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Title)]"
```